# iOS - is there a way to play iPod music in mono sound?

Tags: ios, audio

I'm trying to play music from the iPod and it works fine. Question is, how do I make it play in MONO instead of Stereo?

The only code I have is the standard

```
- (IBAction)playsong:(id)sender
{
    MPMediaPickerController *c = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc]init];
    [c setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:c animated:YES];
    [c autorelease];
}

-(void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    if(mediaItemCollection)
    {
        [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setQueueWithItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
        [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play];
    }
    [mediaPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

In the settings app in iOS, there is an option to set the sound to MONO, can this be accessed through another app programmatically?

Comment: the sound file itself should be mono or stereo not the player.

Comment: I'm aware of that. How can I modify the output so that it plays mono?

Comment: So if its your own sound file then there should be desktop sound tools to make it single channel.  If its a system sound then you would have to record the sound do the above and include the edited sound into your app.  From what i know only record settings (NOT play settings) allow you to change the sound to mono (at record time).

Comment: You obviously don't understand the question. I need to play songs from the ipod music library in mono sound, no matter the format of the songs.